# Ionic 3 PWA for Android Facebook app issue

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

How to open FB app from the Ionic 3 PWA app for Android. I tried with the below codes which work fine with the hybrid app but not opening FB app from PWA.

```
window.open("fb://page/?id=" + appid, "_system", "location=no");
window.open("fb://page/" + appid, "_system", "location=no");
window.open("fb://profile/" + appid, "_system", "location=no");
```

Could you please help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Below is the code i am using to open facebook app in my application. This will open FB app from normal android application. But it opens a white blank page when i am trying with the PWA version of my application.                                                                                 

if (this.platForm.is('ios')) {
          window.open('fb://page/?id=' + userFacebook, "_system", "location=no");
} else {
          window.open('fb://page/' + userFacebook, "_system", "location=no");
}